# Java Applet sandboxed in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, applet, osx-mavericks

Ever since upgrading to Mavericks an Applet we have at work has stopped being able to browse for files if used from Safari, still works on Firefox. The Applet handles upload of files so you can imagine how that might be a problem.

When using it from Safari I see the following messages on the OSX console.

11/5/13 10:27:46.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: java(87926) deny file-read-data /Users/username

Is there some way to fix this or will Applets just not be able to browse the file system on Safari ever again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OSX 10.9/Safari7 plugins are running in sandboxes. These settings are applied on top of Java/Flash/other plugins own security model.

You can manage sandbox security settings on plugin-site basis through Safari preferences / Security tab / Internet plugins.

To allow Java plugin access filesystem outside of sandbox select Unsafe mode.

Comment: That works for some sites (e.g., www.javatester.org) but *not* for others (e.g., calculusapplets.com) when I add them to the exception list for Java plug-in (Java 8 Update 25) in Safari 7.1. I simply don't understand this.